# Getting the real exception from FaultException<>

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I catch a `FaultException` while calling a service API, e.g.

```
catch(FaultException<MyCustomEx> e)
{
    // How do I get the MyCustomEx object here?
}
```

I want to call some method on the `MyCustomEx` object embedded inside.

```
e.getTheActualExc().getMyCustomErrorCode();
```

How do I get the actual object?

Comment: Isn't this the InnerException?

Comment: So the catch statement catches a `FaultException` and the `FaultException` does hold the `MyCustomEx`? Can you post both classes ?

Comment: isn't it `e.Detail`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms576199(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms576199(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms576199%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The required property is `Detail`:

```
try {
  ...
}
catch(FaultException<MyCustomEx> e) {
  MyCustomEx detail = e.Detail;
  ...
}
```

Or, if you have to catch `FaultException` class, you can use *Reflection*:

```
  try {
    ...
  }
  catch (FaultException e) {
    PropertyInfo pi = e.GetType().GetProperty("Detail");

    if (pi != null) {
      Object rawDetail = pi.GetValue(e); 

      MyCustomEx detail = rawDetail as MyCustomEx;

      if (detail != null) {
        ...
      }
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

the e.Detail property will give you the object of the FaultException<> , see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
var serviceFault = exc as FaultException<ExceptionDetail>;

        if (serviceFault != null)
        {
            if (serviceFault.Detail.Type.Equals(typeof(TimeoutException).FullName))
            {

            }
            else if serviceFault.Detail.Type.Equals(typeof(EndpointNotFoundException).FullName))
            {

            }
            .....
        }
```

This is an example of what I used. You can access the type in `Detail`